# Redirect a Subdirectory and any following subdirectories

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am having an issue with a subdirectory that has many different paths, but on the new website we are no longer using that structure. The old website worked this way:

```
example.com/photos/photo-1
example.com/photos/photo-2
example.com/photos/photo-3
```

On our new site we are not using /photos, and my current redirect attempts have not worked

```
Redirect 301 /photos https://example.com/
```

ends up redirecting to

```
example.com/photo-1
example.com/photo-2
example.com/photo-3
```

Removing the photos subdirectory, but still attempting to access the subdirectory that follow it.

The desired result would be for any attempt to access example.com/photos or example.com/photos/* should redirect to homepage at example.com/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^photos/(.+) https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This worked for me and did exactly what I needed. I already can think of multiple client sites that this will come in handy, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please accept this as the answer and upvote if you feel like it

Comment: I am not sure how. Says I need 15 reputation to upvote, and I don't see a button to set this as the accepted answer. I'm new in town. EDIT: Found it!

Comment: No prob. To accept, click on the big checkmark on the left of the answer (under the zero with up/down arrows). I forgot about the reputation thing.

Comment: This answer will result in exactly the same issue as you already describe it in your question: subfolders will not get removed.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is the approach that makes most sense:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?photos/[^/]+/(.+)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

It uses the rewriting module which means that has to be loaded into the http server. That is the standard setup, though.

In case it is not all subfolders that should get redirected you can name a pattern instead. This allows for exceptions. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?photos/photo-\d/+(.+)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

And in case both host are identical for the old and the new "site" you can use an internal redirection to simplify things:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?photos/photo-\d/+(.+)$ /$1 [R=301]
```

In general you should try to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. And only use a distributed configuration file instead (".htaccess") if you have no access to the central configuration. Various reasons.

Comment: I am not sure how to get into the server configuration itself, we use wordpress sites and have easy access to the .htaccess file. That's where all of our Redirects end up.

Either way, Thank you!

Comment: You have access if you operate the http server yourself. If you are just using a web hoster then you have no access and no control to the server configuration.